# IPv6 not working for Ubuntu in AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6

When I launch an instance with IPv6 enabled or attach a network interface (eni) that has IPv6 assignments to an instance running Ubuntu I do not get the IPv6 addresses set up.  There are link-local addresses on the interfaces and "::1/128" on the "lo" interface, showing that the kernel has IPv6 compiled in.  So, maybe the issue is with DHCP or the like.  I have been using the Ubuntu AMI that is among the choices when launching instances via the web console.  IPv6 works for Amazon Linux without any changes to that system.  As soon as I switched my IPv6 efforts to Amazon Linux things started working better.

Is there a real issue with the Ubuntu AMI and IPv6?  Does anyone know a way to get IPv6 working on Ubuntu in AWS EC2?

Answer (score 1):

From the VPC docs, it appears that by default the Ethernet interface and dhclient don't expect IPv6 by default, so this needs to be configured.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#ipv6-dhcpv6-ubuntu